# using jquery to select canvas element

Tags: jquery, canvas, jqplot

I have a dashboard page that has(or moreover can have) multiple charts that are drawn using the jqPlots plugin.

I want to be able to "export" it to an image so a user could simply print off the chart if they so wished.

my speed bump is not getting the image from the canvas but more of how to get the exact canvas i want to print.

my problem is that jqplots doesn't assign the canvas with a unique id to grab it and I'm finding no info on how jquery can find the canvas.

Comment: When you create the chart you pass it the `id` of a div .. just give those `div`s a class ... there are some examples here on how to export a chart to image -> https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/14/export-capabilities or here https://github.com/lsiden/export-jqplot-to-png/blob/master/export-jqplot-to-png.js

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look at these and report back if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution

I used the follow as my base:

https://bitbucket.org/michelts/jqplot/src/18f31b092903/examples/exportImage.html

This helped me get in the right direction.